# Calculating average with SelectedIndices

Tags: c#, sum, average, multi-select, selectedindexchanged

My program reads coordinates(double x,douule y) into ListBox and need to calculate the average of them after choosing them with SelectedIndices and MultiExtended.
The problem is how can I refresh my code with each Multiselection.
As you can see I set SelectedIndices[0] to 0 as default. At the moment my program just making average of the 1st coordinate divided by number of selectedIndices.

If you think about any ways to improve my code I would like to know as well.

Thanks!

```
   private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Average
    {
        int[] selected = new int[] {points_List.SelectedIndices[0] };
        double sumX = 0, sumY = 0; ;
        foreach (int iIndex in selected)
        {
            sumX += points[iIndex].X;
            sumY += points[iIndex].Y;
        }
        averageX = (sumX) / (points_List.SelectedIndices.Count);
        averageY = (sumY) / (points_List.SelectedIndices.Count);
        label1.Text = "Average is: ";
        label1.Text += averageX.ToString();
        label1.Text += "   ";
        label1.Text += averageY.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: You should get interested in re-calculating it when the SelectedIndexChanged event fires.

Answer (score 1):

The correct code will require a cast of `SelectedIndices` through `OfType<T>` or `Cast<T>`. Also, it's convenient to call `ToArray` to materialize the result to avoid having to compute it twice.

```
var selectedPoints = points_List.SelectedIndices.
    OfType<int>().
    Select(i => points[i]).
    ToArray();
var averageX = selectedPoints.Average(p => p.X);
var averageY = selectedPoints.Average(p => p.Y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Final solution, Thanks all.

```
        {
        double averageX = 0, averageY = 0;
        var selectedPoints = from int i in pointsList.SelectedIndices select points[i];
        if (pointsList.SelectedIndices.Count == 0)
        {
            label1.Text = "Average is 0.000 0.000 ";//default text
            return;
        }
        averageX = selectedPoints.Average(p => p.X);
        averageY = selectedPoints.Average(p => p.Y);
        label1.Text = "Average X: ";
        label1.Text += averageX.ToString();
        label1.Text += "   Y:";
        label1.Text += averageY.ToString();
    }
```